# Solving mixed integer programming using Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Let $x_{ij}$ be an $n\times k$ matrix defined as follows:

$
x_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }s_i\text{ is assigned to }S_j  \\
0, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
$

and $S$ is a set of $k$ clusters and $s_i$ is a set of points to be assigned to these clusters.

The following integer programming defition gives the exact solution to k-means clustering:

$
\min_{x_{ij}} \sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} \lVert s_i - \frac{\sum_{l=1}^n x_{lj}s_l}{\sum_{l=1}^n x_{lj}} \rVert^2
$

such that the following cnstraints hold:

$
\sum_{j=1}^k s_{ij} = 1,\ i=1,\ldots,n 
$

$
\sum_{i=1}^n s_{ij} \geq 1,\ j=1,\ldots,k 
$

$
x_{ij}\in\{0,1\},\ i=1,\ldots,n\ \textrm{and}\ j=1,\ldots,k
$

How can this be programmed in Mathematica? Mathematica has a Linear Programming package but the domain specification cannot be set to mixed integers (reals and integers)? Does the following function specification do mixed integer programming:

```
LinearProgramming[c,m,b,lu,{dom1,dom2,…}]
```

The problem is NP-hard so I am not expecting fast solutions...

Comment: As written, it does not look to be linear. I think you meant to use `x` instead of `s` in the summation constraints. It will still need work to make it an ILP, possibly by using a 1-norm for those distances.

Comment: You could use the EM algorithm. A quick demo of this is (1) set up the problem `m=100; n=10; data=RandomReal[{-1,1},{m,2}]; nodes=RandomReal[{-1,1},{n,2}];`, (2) use EM to optimise the nodes `clustering = NestList[(nearfun = Nearest[#]; Mean /@ GatherBy[data, nearfun]) &, nodes, 10];`, (3) plot the sequence of optimisation steps `movieframes = Map[ListPlot[{data, #}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Black, {PointSize[0.02], Red}}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] &, clustering];`, and (4) animate the sequence `ListAnimate[movieframes]`.

Comment: Would be easier if you provide sample input data.

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/j2kun/k-means/blob/master/k-means-animations.nb